# Does the <title> element need to be in the <head> element?

Tags: html

I don't have access to update the title element for many of the pages on my site (a limitation in the e-commerce software I'm using) and I'm wondering if the `<title>` element can be placed within the `<body>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Unfortunately there is already a <title> in side the head.

Answer (score 5):

This is what the W3C has to say about it:

> **7.4.2 The `TITLE` element**
>
> [Every HTML document **must** have a `TITLE` element in the `HEAD`
>   section.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-TITLE)

So no, you can't put the `<title>` tag inside the `<body>` tag.

Contact the developer(s) of said e-commerce software and see if there's a way to change the title of the page, either through the HTML directly or through the administration user interface of the e-commerce software. If you can't, get a different e-commerce software solution.

Answer (score 2):

No. It can't be, doubly so if there's already a `<title>` tag in `<head>`. If you don't have access to the `<title>` in `<head>`, you need to get access.

If you absolutely can't, and there's not already a `<title>` tag, some tests reveal that it will work in `<body>`. However, you shouldn't do this - it's invalid markup.

An alternative is to do it using JavaScript placed in the `<body>` (which you shouldn't do, again):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    function load() {
        document.title = 'The new title';
    }

    if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', load, false);
    } else if(window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', load);
    }
})();
</script>
```

That's only a last-ditch "alternative," though.

Comment: Not having a `<title>` in the `<head>` alone will invalidate the markup.

Answer (score 1):

The title tag has to be in the head tag.

[HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2):

> "Every HTML document must have a TITLE element in the HEAD section."