# Does a page title have to be within the head tags as im using angular

Tags: html, angular, tags

I am using an angular js website there for my page title always remains the same. Does the page title tag have to be within the head tags, is this really important or can I place the title tag within the body or will search engines not like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the <title> element need to be in the <head> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469986/does-the-title-element-need-to-be-in-the-head-element)

Comment: The other post talks about having 2 title tags on the page, Im asking if the title tag has to be in head as i can remove the page title on the index page and put title tags in the angualr html templates.

Comment: it dosen't matter , title needs to be inside head only

Comment: ahhhh well crap

Comment: Are you using Angular 2+ or the original AngularJS? For Angular 2+, there is a way to change the title:  https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title

Comment: Just using angularjs